# PLAY and PAUSE images with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio, mp3

I'm currently using the following to play and pause a music track.

```
function togglePlayPause() {
    var playpause = document.getElementById("playpause");
    if (audio.paused || audio.ended) {
        playpause.title = "pause";
        playpause.innerHTML = "pause";
        audio.play();
    } else {
        playpause.title = "play";
        playpause.innerHTML = "play";
        audio.pause();
    }
}
```

It works great. The text on the button says "Play" and then "Pause" when pressed again.

I would like to use JavaScript to replace the default browser play button with an image, and then replace that image with another(pause) image when pressed again.

I'm thinking I will need to add in an extra class for both play and pause images with the JavaScript.

Can anyone help me edit the code I have to use images instead of the "play" and "pause" title text it's doing now.

Answer (score 0):

You can define "play" and "pause" classes that use your images as their backgrounds. Then just change its class.

```
playpause.className = "myPauseClass"
```

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not doing something right. `function togglePlayPause() { var playpause = document.getElementById("playpause");

 if (audio.paused || audio.ended) { playpause.className = "PauseButton";  audio.play();

 } else {

  playpause.className = "PlayButton";
   audio.pause(); } }`   and I've styled both classes within my css, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Here is my css:  ```.PlayButton{width:90px;height:89px;display:block;background: url("../img/play-sm.png") no-repeat;border:none;}
.PauseButton{width:90px;height:89px;display:block;background: url("../img/pause-sm.png") no-repeat;border:none;}```

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. The button just stays styled with the browser's default button styles.  The html is this: ```<div id="controls"> <button id="playpause" title="play" onclick="togglePlayPause()"></button> </div>```

Comment: Weird. Can you first try setting a background color instead of a background image to see if it works? Maybe your css is not working. Also, you can use <a> instead of <button>.

Comment: This is crazy. So my css is not working for some reason, because changing it's color doesn't do anything either. Plus, if I use <a> instead of <button>, then nothing appears at all. Ugh. Well I really appreciate you trying to help though!

Comment: So maybe your css is not correctly loaded. Mind accepting my answer?

Comment: I take that back. I did get it to work with using just the <a> element. I just can't get it to toggle between the Play image and Pause image. I've declared the button id of "playpause" to be the play button image, and that works. So the css is loading. That is what is odd. It just won't read the change in class when the button is pressed. I don't get it.

Comment: I'm not able to post it all in one comment so I'll do it in a few. Here is the HTML: `<audio controls preload="false" id="audio">
<source src="music/hatcher.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
<source src="music/hatcher.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
Your browser doesn't support the HTML audio tag. Be sad.
</audio>`

Comment: Here is the javascript: `<script>var audio = document.getElementById("audio");  audio.controls = false; </script>

<script>
function togglePlayPause() {
    var playpause = document.getElementById("playpause");
    if (audio.paused || audio.ended) {
        playpause.className = "PauseButton";
        playpause.innerHTML = "pause";
        audio.play();
    } else {
        playpause.className = "PlayButton";
        playpause.innerHTML = "play";
        audio.pause();
    }
}
</script>`

Comment: and finally css: `#playpause{width:90px;height:89px;display:block;background: url("../img/play-sm.png") no-repeat;border:none;}
.PlayButton{width:90px;height:89px;display:block;background: url("../img/play-sm.png") no-repeat;border:none;}
.PauseButton{width:90px;height:89px;display:block;background: url("../img/pause-sm.png") no-repeat;border:none;}`